# MVC framework with Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I have a `TableViewController` which controls all the `Habit` objects. So when they come in from Parse, I take each `PFObject` and make a new `Habit` object from it with their respective properties (name, current streak, date created, user who created it). After loading, the user might delete, edit, add new habits which leaves me question **how I should handle all these modifications?**

Should I keep going with my `Habit` objects and with every modification upload the changes to Parse or simple leave the `Habit` object out of it and deal with `PFObject`s which in turn leaves me to write less code for each modification.

**An example:**

When the user creates a new Habit, I can either create the new `Habit` object **and** the `PFObject` as follows:

```
    Habit *habit = [Habit habitWithTitle:self.habitField.text];
    habit.frequency = self.howOften;
    habit.currentStreak = @0;

    // add it to back end
    PFObject *newHabit = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Habit"];
    newHabit[@"name"] = self.habitField.text;
    newHabit[@"currentStreak"] = @0;
```

or forget about `Habit` class and use `PFObject`s and pass those around:

```
    PFObject *newHabit = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Habit"];
    newHabit[@"name"] = self.habitField.text;
    newHabit[@"frequency"] = self.howOften;
    newHabit[@"currentStreak"] = @0;
```

**Another example** would be when deleting a habit from a `tableViewCell` swipe, I have to create the `PFObject` from the `Habit` object in order to send it to the back end, find it and delete it.

**Where MVC comes in:** 
It is my understanding that in this situation, the `Habit` object is the Model, the View is well the views and the controller is my class that manages the interaction between those two. **Could my model be the PFObjects?**

Answer (score 0):

The only downside if you continue with the above described approach is that if you have multiple Models in your project that you need to convert to PFObject objects, you'll end up with lots of code around these models.

You can write a separate class that will act as a wrapper for dealing with PFObject objects (writing/reading to/from PFObject objects), in that way the logic that is related to mapping your object model (e.g. Habit) to PFObject is centralised in one place.